# Binary file read, twice, before closing file ID

Tags: matlab, file-io

I have a question about file IO in matlab.

When I read a binary file(single type, little endian), I tried to read the file, twice, before closing file.

```
fid=fopen('testSample.bin');

   A = fread(fid,inf,'float32');
   B = fread(fid,inf,'float32');

fclose(fid);
```

A contained data, but B was empty.
So, I closed the file ID and read, again.

```
fid=fopen('testSample.bin');

   A = fread(fid,inf,'float32');

fclose(fid);

fid=fopen('testSample.bin');

   B = fread(fid,inf,'float32');

fclose(fid);
```

And, B contained data.

Is it not possible to read file twice, before closing file ID in Matlab?

Is it common situation in all programming language?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to reset your file pointer at the right position before your second read. To do that you can use [fseek](http://au.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fseek.html).

```
fid=fopen('testSample.bin');

A = fread(fid,inf,'float32');    
fseek(fid, 0, 'bof');
B = fread(fid,inf,'float32');

fclose(fid);
```

Comment: I thought, after finishing reading, file pointer is reset, thank you~